# Hangfire Cron Expression failing

Tags: cron, hangfire

I have a task scheduled like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Process inbound external messages", () => ProcessInboundExternalMessages(), Cron.Minutely);
```

It works.

But I need one to fire ever midnight.

So I tried to create a cron expression:

```
private const string CronDailyAtMidnight = "0 0 * * *";
```

And then assign that to my task.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Deactivate user role allocation on expiry", () => DeactivateUserRoleAllocationOnExpiry(), CronDailyAtMidnight);
```

However, it never fires. Can anyone see an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was - it uses UTC date. Fixed.